# Server always sends RST to some destinations and proper responses to others

Tags: ssl, tcp, get, http-headers, python-requests

We have a server which servers our API.

I'm using it for a while now and nowadays I'm experiencing what I'm calling now a sort of ***server prejudice* from our API server to some destinations** (being nice to some senders and bad to others) and I'd like to know exactly what's going on.

Some **requests are being responded with a TCP reset** (RST), but others **do get to be responded properly** (200 status, expected content).

I want to clarify that this is not explicitly done in the server (we are not actually picking some destinations to reject) and that, for each client I've tried, I always get the same result (I mean, the behavior is deterministic, depending only on the sender - at least apparently).

This is the actual request I'm sending:

```
GET /api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.buddycloud.org
```

This is the python code I wrote and that I'm running at different places:

```
from requests import Request, Session

headers = {
    'Accept' : '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
    'Host' : 'demo.buddycloud.org'
}

req = Request('GET',
'https://demo.buddycloud.org/api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts',
headers=headers)

r = req.prepare()
print r.url

s = Session()
resp = s.send(r, verify=False)

print resp, resp.ok
print resp.content
```

Couple different scenarios I've tried:

**Windows 7 64 bits, Python 2.7.3, Requests 1.2.3**

Ran this code and this exception was raised:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='demo.buddycloud.org', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts
(Caused by <class 'socket.error'>:
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

Using Wireshark I noticed this is happening because I get a TCP reset from the server.
[image: Wireshark output image]

**Ubuntu, Python 2.7.3, Request 1.2.3**

I ran the exact same code and got no problems, but the expected response:

```
https://demo.buddycloud.org/api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts
<Response [200]> True
{
  "title" : "guilherme@buddycloud.org Channel Posts",
  "description":"This is my buddycloud channel =)",
  "access_model":"open",
  "creation_date":"2013-04-13T15:24:53.471Z",
  "channel_type":"personal",
  "default_affiliation":"publisher"
}
```

At this point in the reading, one could guess it is a Windows x Linux problem, but you will see that one of the scenarios is a Linux enviroment but I still got the same problem.

**Through Postman**

It works just fine, as one might expect. [image: Postman printscreen]

**At our Heroku server, Python 2.7.4, Requests 1.2.3**

We have an app that issues the same call to our API. A pretty similar error happens there and I'm sure the reason is the same (server sending TCP resets). This is the exception raised:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='demo.buddycloud.org', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url:
/api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts
(Caused by : [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)
```

So I'm dying to know why is our server behaving like this. I spent a lot of time thinking that the problem was on my end but I'm guessing it isn't and that it is being caused by something at the server, maybe some misconfiguration or something SSL-related.

Note that the headers my code is sending through *python-requests* are the same that Postman sends - I'm actually trying to mock Postman's successful request, but that won't work.

Also please note that I have Python and Requests in the exact same versions everywhere I tried executing this.

Can somebody help me know what's going on? Thanks in advance and I'm open to any further questions you might have.

Comment: I assume you've looked for info in the server logs?  Also, perhaps you should compare the SSL ClientHello details between working and non-working packet captures.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the headers from the successful Requests request and from the unsuccessful one. [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) can probably help you get them if you're strugging with the HTTPS.

Comment: @Lukasa It does not appear to be an issue with HTTP headers.  The packet capture shows that the connection is dropped in the SSL handshake, before HTTP headers are sent.  Using a proxy will alter the behavior (i.e. it may work when the real client doesn't and vice versa) as the proxy will be performing the client side of the handshake.

Comment: Wow guys, thanks for such a quick feedback!

So, I'm guessing @rhashimoto is right, the problem seems to be SSL-related. I tried using t-8ch's code snippet and that worked! Seems to be a problem with the default SSL version used by Requests.

Comment: But I still wonder if there's anything we should have in our server to avoid this problem from happening at all, because throughout this week I've also tried some requests to other API's from my end and they worked just fine.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos I believe the problem is that your server does not accept a SSL2 ClientHello, even if the SSL2 ClientHello promises support for SSL3 or TLS1.  Most servers will respond to an SSL2 ClientHello with an "upgrade" to SSL3 or TLS1, but because SSL2 has been deprecated for a long time some platforms may be dropping that feature.  If you want further information you'll have to provide details about how your server side is configured, either here or in a new question.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos you should probably review your ssl configuration in general. Explicit `SSL2` breaks, explicit `SSL3` gives an expired certificate, `TLS1` works. (checkout the `-1`, `-2` and `-3` flags of `curl`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with ssl negotiation. This code works for me on heroku.
Using `'SSLv3'` also works. `'SSLv23'` (the default) breaks, dont' ask me why.

```
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    '''An HTTPS Transport Adapter that uses an arbitrary SSL version.'''
    def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version

        super(SSLAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=self.ssl_version)

s = Session()
s.mount('https://', SSLAdapter('TLSv1'))
req = s.get('https://demo.buddycloud.org/api/guilherme@buddycloud.org/metadata/posts',    verify=False)
print(req)
```

(The `SSLAdapter` is from the blog of @Lukasa)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @t-8ch! This code snippet not only worked on Heroku, but on every other scenario I've tried so far!

Sorry I am new here, I don't have 15 points so I can't upvote your answer yet (makes no sense), but once I do be sure I'll come back here to do so. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/)'s the link to the relevant blog post. =)

Comment: Thank you as well, @Lukasa. Definetely going to read that post.

Answer (score 0):

Problem looks to be with Request headers.

Add following headers to your requests -

```
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

Remove following headers from your requests -

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Test again, should work.